# MacLaurin k/ k^2+1

Tags: taylor-expansion

The MacLaurin series for 
$\frac{1}{1+k}$
$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n k^n$

use the series above to find the MacLaurin series for 
$\frac{k}{1+k^2}$

I found the series is 
$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n k^{2n+1}$
but I'm not sure how can we use the first series to find out the series for $\frac{k}{1+k^2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{1+k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n k^n$$
let $k\to k^2$
$$\frac{1}{1+k^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n k^{2n}$$
then multiply by $k$

Answer (score 0):

in the first expansion,
you can replace $k$  by  $k^2$ since

$k^2$ tends to $0$ when $k$ goes to 0.

then you multiply by $k$.

your result is correct.

YOU CAN NOT REPLACE k by something which does not go to 0 when k goes to 0.!!